# how to start NetLogo with java7 under OSX mavericks?

Tags: java, netlogo

I have just installed osx mavericks, and Java SE6 just disappeared from my system... anyway, I already have Java SE7 and I am happy with that, no need to reinstall Java SE6 since my NetBeans already works on Java7 and NetLogo too if I start it from terminal...

I am wondering how to tell the plist file of my NetLogo 5.0.4 to look for the JavaSE7 folder... any help much appreciated.

Best,
Simone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

You might think that changing "1.5" to "1.7" in these Info.plist lines:

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.5+</string>
```

would work, but it doesn't. That's because Java 6 is from Apple but Java 7 is from Oracle, and "Apple java applications and Oracle's aren't executable compatible" ([source](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jul/msg00020.html)).

Unless you want to mess with making a new NetLogo app bundle using Oracle's AppBundler tool, the simplest way to get the app running under Java 7 is to download the Linux version of NetLogo and use the supplied `netlogo.sh` launch script.

**More info**

When running headless, NetLogo has been tested thoroughly on Java 7. For headless runs, I definitely recommend Java 7 because it's faster.

The NetLogo GUI, however, hasn't been tested with Java 7. Once you get it launched, it will probably mostly work, but you might have problems or incompatibilities. We'll probably switch eventually (it's [issue 197](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/197)), but the work on that hasn't been done yet. That ticket would be a good place to record any problems that you find.

If you decide to fall back to Java 6, you can get it from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 . (link is current as of October 2013)

Comment: Thanks Seth, but how is it that NetBeans for MacOSX works with Java7? I haven't recompiled anything, just downloaded it and then changed the conf file to point to the Java7 from Oracle... I thought I could do something similar for NetLogo too...

Comment: and by the way NetLogo (started from bash) works perfectly with Java 7 in my case

Comment: I think I have to read more carefully... that's because Netbeans is from Oracle... got it.

Comment: perhaps Oracle's app bundler stuff (which NetLogo is not using — yet?) is backwards compatible with both Apple Java and Oracle Java.